# Não estou conseguindo executar a máscara monetária pelo Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando configurar minhas inputs com máscara monetária. Chamei o script da seguinte forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dist/jquery.mask.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.money2').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});
</script>
```

Criei a seguinte input:

```
<h4 id="cr1">Até 30 dias<input type="text" placeholder="R$ 0,00" id="cr11" name="ncr11" class="money2"/></h4>
```

Também já tentei substituir o $('.money2') por $('#cr11') na tentativa chamar pelo id.

Em ambos os casos (class ou id) não funcionou, como é possível observar pela imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Já deveria chamar a máscara neste campo, correto?

Comment: Qual que é o plugin de máscara que vc ta usando ? o Jquery inputmask ou outro ? manda o link de onde vc baixou ele aqui no comentário

Comment: Verifique se os scripts estão sendo carregados normalmente. Aperte F12 e veja se o navegador não apresenta nenhum erro.
Aproveitando, utilizei seu código [neste fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pco4om7/838/) e o mesmo está funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Olá AnthraxisBR, baixei do seguinte link: https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/archive/master.zip

Comment: Olá Randrade, aparece este código no console : XMLHttpRequest síncrono não deve ser usado na thread principal devido a seus efeitos prejudiciais para a experiência de usuário. Para mais informações http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/ (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4:15845)

Comment: Não estou conseguindo resolver amigos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Têm dois problemas no seu código:

1. Nunca importe uma lib e execute código JavaScript dentro da mesma
   tag `<script>`.
2. Faltou vc fechar a chamada `$(document).ready(function(){})`.

Sendo assim, o código fica:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dist/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.money2').mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Perfeito Lucas. Muito obrigado.